# jquery 1.7.1 - Syntax error caused by paranthese "(" in querystring

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, query-string

In a MVC View I add a string value to the querystring by ActionLink

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li data-role="list-divider">Select Item</li>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <li>@Html.ActionLinkitem.Name, "Create", "Article", new { idItem = item.Id, name = item.Name }, null)</li>
  }
</ul>
```

I am using jQueryMobile and jQuery. The result is a inset list:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-inset.html

When the link is clicked in the browser I get a JScript runtime error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   data-url='/Article/Create?idItem=152&name=Semi%20Skimmed%20(Lowfat]')

I've tried both:

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(item.Name)
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Name)
```

with no luck.

Elements that does not have "(" or any other special characters in their name are doing just fine. The ]' character in the JScript error seems to point to a serialization (json) which is not successful.

The string from the database is

> "Semi Skimmed (Lowfat)"

and does not contain the ]' part.

Comment: You specified 1.7.1: have you tried with the latest jQuery 1.7.2?

Comment: Where does the `data-url` come from? Are you using jQuery mobile?

Comment: @Spudley no, that's a good idea. I'll update my jQuery version.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that's correct. I'm referencing both jQuery and jQueryMobile library

Answer (score 2):

A goofy work around would be to:

1. Replace "(" and ")" with a special character (or string) that you are sure will be unique (and won't be mangled by urlEncode), such as "~1~" and "~2~".
2. Run the Server.urlEncode method on your string.
3. Replace "~1~" (or whatever) with "(" and "~2~" with ")".

Comment: Yes, I've considered a similar approach, or even removed the name property from the querystring as the id would be sufficient. But I'd like to know whether this is a know problem with a solution on which I can implement, before I implement a workaround

Comment: I just put together a quick test, and used similar values as your question and everything is working together correctly. As was posted in the comments where is data-url coming from and what are you doing with jquery to make this error occur.

Comment: the data-url is coming from jquerymobile

Comment: can you update your question with the actual code that is generating the data-url? Asp.net mvc handles parentheses correctly in normal action links between controllers and views and my answer really isn't relavant. Whatever is happening with jquery is where your error lies.

Comment: The data-url is being created by jqueryMobile. I've updated the question, but I do not know where the data-url is generated in jqueryMobile. As a workaround I am getting the value in the controller method instead of just passing them from the origin view.